# pg_query_params providing date parameters with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

```
pg_query_params( SELECT * FROM example WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'), array() );
```

Above syntax will work, but how can I provide dates dynamically with `pg_query_params`?

I have tried

```
pg_query_params( SELECT * FROM example WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL $1), array('1 day') );
pg_query_params( SELECT * FROM example WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL $1 day), array('1') );
```

and several other combinations but they do not seem to work.
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
pg_query_params('SELECT * FROM example WHERE date >= (NOW() - $1::interval)', array('1 day') );
```

Comment: Worked. How did you figure this out?

Comment: pure luck - I used to use cast instead defining type before value, like `now() - '2016-01-01'::timestamptz` instead of `now() - timestamptz '2016-01-01'` and so on. So I just rewrote your QRY to be cosy with and it worked from first try.